# how to minimize a function under Anneal method with bounds?

Tags: scipy

I am trying to minimize a function with `method = 'Anneal'`
I have specified the bounds in a dictionary called `opts` with `'lower': 0.0` and `'upper': 1.0`
I pass `opts` in the options argument.
The optimization works and I get an answer.
However the values of the best solution are above the upper bound set by me.
Any idea what I am doing wrong? Should bounds be set in any other way?

Comment: I don't think *scipy anneal* respects the bounds. Please see this [scipy issue report](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1653).

Comment: so, is there any alternative method I can use for a constrained bounded minimization. I found that slsqp also does not strictly observe the bounds. It goes out by very very small quantities.

Comment: Please suggest a method that is a global optimizer and does not require derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

If you are requiring an optimizer that respects bounds specifications and that do not require derivatives:

*scipy* contains [fmin_cobyla](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_cobyla.html#scipy.optimize.fmin_cobyla) that supports any type of constraints and does not require derivatives. It is not a global optimizer (but on the other hand I don't believe simulated annealing can guarantee global optimzality either).

[NLOpt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_Python_Reference) has a Python interface and contains the more efficient *BOBYQA* algorithm for nonlinear optimization with variable bounds.